@media in CSS doesn't work as expected in React with grid
In my React app I have a grid element .container, I have a style for it and media request in it.
Here is Products.jsx:
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import classes from "./Products.module.css"
import Product from "../Product/Product"
                    
export default function Products(props) {
  return (
    <main>
        <div className={classes.container}>
          {props.items.map(el =>(
            <Product item={el} key={el.id} />
          ))}    
        </div>                                                                     
    </main>  
  )
}

here is "./Products.module.css"
.container{    
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 25%);   
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .container{
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 50%);
    }
} 

The problem is that in browsers the media request starts working when the screen width is 1973px,
but when I change the version from desktop to mobile, it works properly.
I made the same layout and styles without using React, and it also works properly, so I think the problem is with React.

Everything is working as expected; I don't see any problem with the media query.

I guess you have another media query or styles that are conflicting with this one. You can check it in the developer tools.

no i havent another media query or styles, styles in devtools change when the screen width is 1973px, but in media query i ve setted the value 1024px, it is strange

It works fine for me; I don't see any reason except that other media or styles are included. Could you use simple tags like div, span, etc., instead of Product?

i ve opened my project in firefox and it works as i needed but for some reason in chrome it works diffrently, the problem is not in the Product component

I used Chrome and it works as expected lol. So there could be a few things: grid-template-columns(10%) or repeat(45%) or auto-fill(45%) support. need to check.

можем пойти в дискорд? Я не очень понимаю что мне делать

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
